# a simple inequality for a monotone function

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, monotone-functions

To prove that the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{n^2+1} - n$ is monotone I used $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and got $\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2+1}-1$, which is always negative, but that's as far as I'm able to process it, how do I show formally that it's less than $0$?

($n$ is in $\mathbb N_+$)

Comment: the sequence is monotone decreasing, which you have shown ... what do you need more?

Comment: Have I? I don't feel like the last equality shows that well enough and I thought there is something more that can be done...

Comment: If you have doubts, you could post your proof for $a_{n+1} - a_{n} \le 0$.

Comment: Seems like the issue was way less complicated than i thought, thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a_n=1/b_n$ with $b_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}+n$, and $b_n$ is clearly $>0$ and increasing, so $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: That's a very clever way to go about it, how often can I utilize this with other sequences?

Comment: If you have $a_n=1/b_n$, and if $a_n>0$ (and so $b_n>0$), you can easily see that $a_n$ is increasing iff $b_n$ id decreasing, and $a_n$ is decreasing iff $b_n$ is inceasing. Here the fact is that the sequence $b_n$ is much simpler than $a_n$.